# SOQL - Writing nested join queries

Tags: sql, join, salesforce, soql

I want to write a nested join SQL query in SOQL but am not able to get it right after many attempts. Could someone please help out and explain what I'm getting wrong? TIA

SQL query:

```
SELECT O.ID, A.ID, A.AccountName, OP.Product2Name
FROM
[ORDER] O

JOIN
ACCOUNT A
    ON O.AccountID = A.ID

JOIN
    {
    SELECT P.ID, P.ProductName
        FROM
        ORDERITEM I
        JOIN
        PRODUCT2 P
        ON I.Product2ID = P.ID
    } AS OP
    ON OP.OrderID = O.OrderID
```

SOQL query I'm trying after all refinements:

```
SELECT ORDER.ID, ACCOUNT.ID, ACCOUNT.NAME, PRODUCT2.ID, PRODUCT2.NAME 
FROM ORDER, PRODUCT2, ACCOUNT, ORDERITEM
WHERE (ORDER.ID IN (SELECT ORDERID FROM ORDERITEM)) AND (PRODUCT2.ID IN 
(SELECT PRODUCT2ID FROM ORDERITEM)) AND (ACCOUNT.ID IN (SELECT ACCOUNTID IN ORDER))
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to retrieve? Orders with Account Name, order line items and names of products on these line items? Are you positive you want answer in Salesforce SOQL? Because the syntax is bit different from normal SQL, for example there's no "JOIN" keyword... you'll have lots of reading to do, maybe try a trailhead course on SOQL first?

If you want your main object in the query to be an Order, then go down (to related list of line items), then up again (from line item to product) then something like this should give you a good idea:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name,
    (SELECT Id, OrderItemNumber, Product2.Name
    FROM OrderItems)
FROM Order
```

Not a single `JOIN`, `ON` or even `WHERE` but the result is similar to left outer join in normal database. The join between order and account is solved by adding the dot (`Account.Name`) and the join to related list is done with subquery

Answer (score -1):

Is there any possibility to add in the query a "where" from OrderItems? I'm asking about something like
    `SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name,
    (SELECT Id, OrderItemNumber, Product2.Name
    FROM OrderItems)
FROM Order where Product2.Name ='xxxxxx'`